# What are some good resouces around compressed NFTs?

Tags: nft

Just want to learn more and see some cool resources in the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to use compressed NFTs on Solana](https://solana.com/news/how-to-use-compressed-nfts-on-solana) is a good place to start.

[Creating Compressed NFTs with JavaScript](https://docs.solana.com/developing/guides/compressed-nfts) developer guide if you're interested in code.

Answer (score 5):

There are some examples here:

- https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/compression/cnft-vault/anchor
- https://github.com/Aiyualive/program-examples/tree/bob/cutils

I actually created a video tutorial on this as well:
https://youtu.be/VpCEjrJI2kw